# reading text file to get the output in <levelnumber> <tag> <argument>

Tags: python

I am reading data from text file. the data in the file has a structure

```
<level number> <tag> <argument>
 0 @I5@ INDI
 1 NAME Rosy /Huleknberg/
 2 GIVN Rosy
 2 SURN Huleknberg
 2 _MARNM Vettle
 1 SEX F
 1 BIRT
 2 DATE 15 SEP 1928
 1 DEAT Y
 2 DATE 10 MAR 2010
 1 FAMS @F3@
 0 @I6@ INDI
 1 NAME Roger /Rsoberg/
 2 GIVN Roger
 2 SURN Rsoberg
 2 _MARNM Rsoberg
 1 SEX M
 1 BIRT
 2 DATE 23 JAN 1928
 1 FAMS @F2@
```

I want to read this data and store respective values in 3 variables 'levelnumber' , 'tag' and 'argument'

I wrote a following code to do this operation

```
              testfile = open ('test.dat')
               for line in gedcom_file:
              lines = line.strip() 

              a = lines[:1]
              data.append(a)
              b = lines [1]
              data.append(b)
              c =lines [2:] 
              data.append(c)
```

and got the following output( showing few lines of output)

```
             0

             @I5@ INDI
             1

             NAME Rosy /Huleknberg/
             2

             GIVN Rosy
             2

             SURN Huleknberg
             2

             _MARNM Vettle
             1

             SEX F
             1
```

my output is in the form

```
             <levelnumber>
             <tag> <argument>
```

and I want  all of them on the same line

```
             <levelnumber> <tag> <argument>
```

How can i correct my code? Is there any other method to do this task in better way?

Comment: Your code has broken indentation. `gedcom_file` is not defined. Your code doesn't produce any output.

Comment: If you're looking for inspiration or test cases or existing working code libraries, there's a page here http://www.tamurajones.net/OpenSourceGEDCOMParsers.xhtml with open source GEDCOM parsers. It warns that "Creating a GEDCOM file from your own application is fairly straightforward, reading a random ostensible GEDCOM file created by another application considerably less so" because of inconsistencies in the format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't described clearly, but I hope this will help:

You should use `line.split()` method instead of `line.strip()`

```
testfile = open('test.dat')
for line in gedcom_file:
    # I suppose that data is a list
    data += line.split()
```

And remember that `print('string')` will add newline character at the end of output. `print('string', end='')` output hasn't newline char.

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1. Parsing the file**

This part of your code isn't doing what you intended it to do:

> ```
> lines = line.strip() 
> a = lines[:1]
> b = lines[1]
> c = lines[2:]
> ```

`lines` is a string. So `lines[:1]` is the first character of the string, `lines[1]` is the second character of the string, and `lines[2:]` is the rest of the string.

Instead, after stripping your string, you want to split it into words with [`split(' ', 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). The second argument tells it to split at only the first two spaces, so that the third element of the resulting list is allowed to contain spaces:

```
lines = line.strip().split(' ', 2)
a = lines[0]
b = lines[1]
c = lines[2]
```

Or more succinctly:

```
a, b, c = line.strip().split(' ', 2)
```

**Part 2. Printing a list**

Once you're done processing and have a list you want to print, you can use [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to assemble it into a space-separated string. For example:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(' '.join(my_list))
# a b c
```